# This WSDL is working in SOAP UI but not in .NET framework

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Please help me to verify this WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://VendorService/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://VendorService/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">&lt;font color='#a31515' size='3'&gt;&lt;b&gt;This web service acts as a receiver to accept the car transactions from ETravel tool.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://VendorService/">
          <s:element name="TestService">
            <s:complexType />
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="TestServiceResponse">
            <s:complexType />
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="getServiceData">
            <s:complexType />
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="getServiceDataResponse">
            <s:complexType />
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="PushTrackingUpdates">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                <s:element type="tns:ArrayOfTransactionDetails" name="inputParameters" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
            <s:complexType name="ArrayOfTransactionDetails">
                <s:sequence>
                <s:element type="tns:TransactionDetails" name="TransactionDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          <s:element name="PushTrackingUpdatesResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PushTrackingUpdatesResult" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="TransactionDetails" type="tns:TransactionDetails" />
          <s:complexType name="TransactionDetails">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CarTransactionId" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmployeeNumber" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Designation" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BusinessUnit" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Gender" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmailID" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TravelRequestNumber" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WBSNumber" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestRaisedBy" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestRaiseDate" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Approver" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ApproverRemarks" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PurposeOfTravel" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CompanyCode" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BillingAddress" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ProjectName" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AdditionalTravelInformation" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CarType" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RentalDate" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UsageType" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PickUpTime" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ContactNo" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TravelDesk" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FromDate" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ToDate" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmployeeRemarks" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="NumberOfPersons" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OthercityifOutstation" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Location" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DutyCity" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PickUpPoint" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FromTime" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ToTime" type="s:string"/>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ApproximateCost" type="s:string"/>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OtherRequestType" type="s:string"/>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GuestEmailID" type="s:string"/>
            </s:sequence>
            <s:anyAttribute />
          </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="TestServiceSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestService" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="TestServiceSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestServiceResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getServiceDataSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getServiceData" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getServiceDataSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getServiceDataResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="PushTrackingUpdatesSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PushTrackingUpdates" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="PushTrackingUpdatesSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PushTrackingUpdatesResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="PushTrackingUpdatesTransactionDetails">
        <wsdl:part name="TransactionDetails" element="tns:TransactionDetails" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="VendorServiceBinding">
        <wsdl:operation name="TestService">
          <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;font color='blue'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Function - &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;None, confirms the web-service &amp; db access to the calling component.//// Custom Notes//&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:TestServiceSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:TestServiceSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getServiceData">
          <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;font color='blue'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Function - &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;None, confirms the web-service &amp; db access to the calling component.//// Custom Notes//&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:getServiceDataSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:getServiceDataSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="PushTrackingUpdates">
          <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;font color='blue'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Function - &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;Receives the travel requests from the Etravel tool.//// Custom Notes//&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:PushTrackingUpdatesSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:PushTrackingUpdatesSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="VendorServiceBinding" type="tns:VendorServiceBinding">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="TestService">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://VendorService/TestService" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:customer" name="customerResponse" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="getServiceData">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://VendorService/getServiceData" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="PushTrackingUpdates">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://VendorService/PushTrackingUpdates" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>  
      <wsdl:service name="VendorService">
        <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">&lt;font color='#a31515' size='3'&gt;&lt;b&gt;This web service acts as a receiver to accept the car transactions from ETravel tool.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:port name="VendorServiceBinding" binding="tns:VendorServiceBinding">
          <soap:address location="http://localhost/Vericheck/VendorService.php" />
        </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: What are you doing with this in .NET ? How are you using it?

Comment: I can easily import that WSDL as a Service Reference into my .NET project (VS 2013) - what problems are you having? You need to tell us more about what you're trying to do and what doesn't work!

Comment: I've develop server code in PHP and provide this to one of my .net client. They are not able to use this. it's throwing error. Pushing the data to our system, PushTrackingUpdates method is not working, It seems there is some problem in definitions part

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the maxOccurs="unbounded". 
A specific version of VS has problems with WSDLs and ComplexTypes using this...

I Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It occurs using a sequence of another sequence and .NET has problems creating the xml-serialisation. 
Do add a temp attribute after the sequence. This worked for me.

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfTransactionDetails">
<s:sequence>
    <s:element type="tns:TransactionDetails" name="TransactionDetails" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    </s:sequence>
    <!-- ADD HERE -->
    <xsd:attribute name="tmp" type="xsd:string" />**
</s:complexType>
```

Also see http://webservices20.blogspot.co.at/search?q=Unable+to+generate+a+temporary+class

Greets Rene